# MVC Display Template for Summing Totals

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to display summary totals in a table-footer WITHOUT creating a special property in the view-model.

**However...the footer code fails, saying:**

> "Templates can be used only with field access, property access,
>   single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer
>   expressions."

**FOOTER CODE LOOKS LIKE:**

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="6" class="bg-gray"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            Totals DO NOT include Price Consessions
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Entities.Sum( x => x.Price))
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model.Entities.Sum(x => x.AnnualFee))
        </td>
        <td>
            &nbsp;
        </td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just leave out the `@Html.DisplayFor` and put `@Model.Entities.Sum( x => x.Price)`

Comment: Hahahaha...yeah...that is true.  But, do you HAVE a display template?  Thanks man.